# What is the data structure in python that can contain multiple pandas data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a function to return several data frames (different dims) and put them into a larger "container" and then select each from the "container" using indexing. I think I want to find some data structure like list in R, which can have different kinds of objects.

What can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done much with `Panels`, but what exactly is the functionality that you need? Is there a reason a simple python list wouldn't work? Or, if you want to refer by name and not just by list position, a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit what you want to achieve. People used to work a lot with `MultiIndex` and have an identifier of the dataframe as an index ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex)).

But recently, there has been a lot of improvements of the `Panels` class, which is most likely the optimal solution for you ([api](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Panel.html), [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#panel))

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @foobar I have used MultiColumns and MultiIndexes before for this type of Data.  However, I believe the best datatype for this would be to use a pandas Panel.  Here is the documentation...

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Panel.html

You can add the frames on just like you would add elements to a dict